# Long To XMLGregorianCalendar and back to Long

Tags: java, date, jaxb

I am trying to convert from millisecond time stamp to XMLGregorianCalendar and back, but I seem to be getting wrong results. Am I doing something wrong? It seems I am gaining days.

```
    // Time stamp   01-Jan-0001 00:00:00.000
    Long ts = -62135740800000L;
    System.out.println(ts);
    System.out.println(new Date(ts)); // Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 1 .. Cool!

    // to Gregorian Calendar
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTimeInMillis(ts);

    // to XML Gregorian Calendar
    XMLGregorianCalendar xc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);

    // back to GC
    GregorianCalendar gc2 = xc.toGregorianCalendar();

    // to Timestamp
    Long newTs = gc2.getTimeInMillis();
    System.out.println(newTs);    //  -62135568000000  .. uh?
    System.out.println(new Date(newTs));  // Mon Jan 03 00:00:00 PST 1  .. where did the extra days come from?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting - it works fine for values down to (about) -10000000000000L (and positive values) but larger negative values become inconsistent.

If you print out `gc`, `xc`, and `gc2`, you can see where the problem arises (the conversion from XMLGregorianCalendar to GregorianCalendar

```
gc:  java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=-62135740800000 ... DAY_OF_WEEK=7
xc:  0001-01-01T08:00:00.000Z
gc2: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=? ... DAY_OF_WEEK=5
```

If you print out the fields of `xc`, you get 1,1,1.

```
    System.out.println(xc.getYear());
    System.out.println(xc.getMonth());
    System.out.println(xc.getDay());
```

For `gc2`, you get 1,0,1 (which matches `xc`, because months are zero-based in GregorianCalendar)

```
    System.out.println(gc2.get(gc2.YEAR));
    System.out.println(gc2.get(gc2.MONTH));
    System.out.println(gc2.get(gc2.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

However, adding these 3 `println` calls changes the output from printing out `gc2`! -  the `time=?` output from `gc2` changes to `time=-62135568000000` - so some calculation has been triggered by querying the `GregorianCalendar` object; the `areFieldsSet` property also changes from `false` to `true`.

The timezones of the two GregorianCalendars are different, but this does not account for the error, which persists even if you set explicit TimeZone and Locale.

Comment: If I add `gc2.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR);` then the day is correct, but now the YEAR is off by 1969 years.

Comment: That's odd - I don't see that! The day stays wrong and the year is still 1. I wonder whether it depends on the version of Java (I am using 1.6.0_27) or the Locale (I am `en_GB`)..???

Answer (score -1):

I believe here is the problem. Per documentation, `toGregorianCalendar()`  relies on the `GregorianCalendar` corresponding  defaults for conversion when there is any field missing.

If you try:

```
Date date = new Date();
long ts = date.getTime(); //in place of your input
```

and run your code, you should find, both `to` and `from` conversion working fine.

If you want your `toGregorianCalendar()` with custom provide inputs as in your example, please use `toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone,Locale,Defaults)` and supply the updated defaults to be used in conversion.